# Why do I have to deal with Access-Control-Allow-Origin when using XMLHttpRequest() but not with forms?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cors, cross-domain

I have problem making a request using XMLHttpRequest() and get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin erro but when I use form like below I don't see any problem. Does form somehow allow access, what is the reason for this difference?

```
const f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute("method", 'post');
f.setAttribute("action", '****');

const f = document.createElement("input");
f.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
f.setAttribute("name", 'id');
f.setAttribute("value", token);

document.appendChild(f);
$frm.submit(f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is being set for **cross-domain** requests.
So when you do **cross-domain** request via `XMLHttpRequest()` you have to allow the request origin.

Forms do **same domain** requests, so `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is unnecessary.